# How to iterate over a variable name in perl

Tags: perl

1. I have a subroutine which uses an array and a scalar as its input.
2. I need to use this subroutine by change its array name and scalar value in a for loop.
3. The code of this subroutine is actually more complex, here is just an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @alphanum_0 = (0, 0, 0);
my @alphanum_1 = (1, 1, 1, 1);
my @alphanum_A = ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A');
my @alphanum_B = ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B');

my $MyString = "01ab";
my @MyArray = split(//, uc($MyString));
my $ArrayRef = "\\\@alphanum_$MyArray[2]";

print "$ArrayRef\n";
&test_sub($ArrayRef, "myvar");     #this line does not work
&test_sub(\@alphanum_A, "myvar");  #this line works as my wish

sub test_sub {
    my @tmp_array = @{$_[0]};
    my $tmp_var = $_[1];
    print "$#tmp_array, @tmp_array, $tmp_var\n"
}
```

As you can see, I need to assign the input array by a variable.
How can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: In general, everyone would get better answers if they did two simple things: Provide expected and actual results.

Comment: I take it you are trying to break `strict` rules to iterate over various arrays, e.g. create the string `alphanum_0` and then try to get a reference to the array `@alphanum_0`. This is very bad practice, and not possible to do while using `strict`. You should use a hash instead, e.g. `$hash{'alphanum_0'} = \@alphanum_0;`

Comment: @TLP I know that's a bad idea to go this way, but thank you! I think that I might got the picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an HoA

```
my %alphanum = (
    0 => [0, 0, 0],
    1 => [1, 1, 1, 1],
    A => ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    B => ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
);

my $ArrayRef = $alphanum{ $MyArray[2] };
```